# JSON Referencing Previous Properties

Tags: javascript, json

I saw a question similar to mine on Stackoverflow but most folks simply provided various work arounds, which I'm not looking for.

I want a property in my JSON to be able to refer to an previous property in the same object:

```
var x = {
   a : 1,
   b : a + 1
};
```

I've tried `b : this.a + 1`, but that doesn't work.

Why can't I define "b" in terms of "a"? Again, I'm not looking for workarounds, just insight and understanding.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do that.  When you make an object, it and its properties don't exist until after the statement is done.  You can't reference the object or its properties at the point of creation.

You can do it like this:

```
var x = {a: 1};
x.b = x.a + 1;
```

P.S. That's *not* JSON.  It's a JavaScript object.  JSON is a *string representation* of data, that just so happens to very closely resemble JavaScript syntax.  `var x = {a: 1}` is an object, `'{"a": 1}'` (a string) is JSON.

Answer (score 0):

`this` is the global object, so in your example, it doesn't have `a` property.

You could see that with a simple example in your browser console

```
var object = { test: this };
console.log(object);
```

You will se that `object` is the `Window` object.